# Filter for duplicate values.

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add a filter to check for duplicate values that a user might input. I am not sure where I am going going wrong in my query.

My query doesnot enter the loop to check if the name already exists.

I am fairly new to google-could. If someone can tell me on how I can fix my problem or if there is a better solution.

```
    else if ( commandEls[0].equals( "add_director" ) ) {
        String name = commandEls[1];
        String gender = commandEls[2];
        String date_of_birth = commandEls[3];


        boolean duplicate = false;
        //add a director record with the given fields to the datastore, don't forget to check for duplicates

        Entity addDirectorEntity = new Entity("Director");

        // check if the entity already exits 
        // if !duplicate add, else "Already exisits"

        Query directorExists = new Query("Movies");

        // Director Name is the primary key
        directorExists.addFilter("directorName",Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, name);
        System.out.print(name);
        PreparedQuery preparedDirectorQuery = datastore.prepare(directorExists);

        System.out.print("outside");    
        for(Entity directorResult : preparedDirectorQuery.asIterable()){
            // result already exists in the database
            String dName = (String) directorResult.getProperty(name);
            System.out.print(dName);
            System.out.print("finish");
            duplicate = true;
        }

        if(!duplicate){ 
            addDirectorEntity.setProperty("directorName",name);
            addDirectorEntity.setProperty("directorGender",gender);
            addDirectorEntity.setProperty("directorDOB",date_of_birth);

            try{
                datastore.put(addDirectorEntity);
                results = "Command executed successfully!";
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                results = "Error";
            }
        }

        else {
            results = "Director already exists!";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a valid thing to do but i figured out my problem. 
I am making an Entity for Director where as That should be for movies.

Answer (score 0):

Non-ancestor queries (like the one in your example) are eventually consistent, so they cannot reliably detect duplicate property values. Ancestor queries are fully consistent, but they require structuring your data using entity groups, and that comes at the cost of write throughput.

If the `directorName` property in your example is truly unique, you could [use it as the name in the key](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Kinds_and_identifiers) of your `Director` entities. Then, when you are inserting a new `Director` entity, you can first check if it already exists (inside of a transaction).

There's no general, built-in way in Datastore to ensure the uniqueness of a property value. This related [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=178) contains discussion of some possible strategies for approximating a uniqueness constraint.

I'd also recommend reading up on [queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries) and [consistency](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency) in the Datastore.